# how to select content in WPF datagrid as like html table

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, datagrid, html-table

I'm having WPF DataGrid, in that I'm using DataGridTextColumn to display the Text Content. I need to Select the Text as like as HTML Table.

> Note: Kindly Use the `SelectionUnit="FullRow"` and don't use any readonly TextBox Control

My WPF XAML Source Code:

```
<DataGrid  AutoGenerateColumns="False" ItemsSource="{Binding MobileList, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" SelectionUnit="FullRow" IsReadOnly="True">
    <DataGrid.InputBindings>
        <KeyBinding Key="C" Modifiers="Ctrl" Command="{Binding Path=DataContext.CopyToClipBoardCommand}" CommandParameter="{Binding }" />
    </DataGrid.InputBindings>
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <!--Column 1-->
        <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding MobileName}" Header="Name" />
        <!--Column 2-->
        <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding MobileOS}" Header="OS" />
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

The Output Screen for this WPF Window is

[image: Select the Content as like HTML Table]

The C# Source Code associated with the XAML DataGrid

```
public class GridViewModel
{
    public ObservableCollection<MobileInfo> MobileList { get; set; }

    public GridViewModel()
    {
        MobileList = new ObservableCollection<MobileInfo>();
        MobileList.Add(new MobileInfo  { MobileName = "iPhone", MobileOS = "iOS" });
        MobileList.Add(new MobileInfo { MobileName = "Xperia", MobileOS = "Android" });
        MobileList.Add(new MobileInfo { MobileName = "Lumina", MobileOS = "Windows" });
    }

}

public class MobileInfo
{
    public string MobileName { get; set; }
    public string MobileOS { get; set; }
}
```

The Relative HTML Version for the above Collection is

```html
<html>
<head>
<title>HTML DataGrid</title>
</head>
<body>
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>OS</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>iPhone</td>
      <td>iOS</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Xperia</td>
      <td>Android</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Lumina</td>
      <td>Windows</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: So you want to copy one datagrid and paste it as a html markup (table)? Is this assumption correct?

Comment: @SatyakiChatterjee - not exactly but correct. I need the selection functionality as like HTML Table.

Comment: Why you don't want to use a styled readonly TextBox?

Comment: DataGridTextColumn inherits the TextBlock by default. If we use the Read only TextBox means we have to use DataGridTemplateColumn.

Comment: And what's wrong with DataGridTemplateColumn?

Comment: @chameleon86 - Undauntedly I don't like to increase the weight to the DataGrid. To displaying the Text DataGridTextColumn is enough. In my Project there is more than 500 DataGrid's are there. Right-now we are fine-tuning our application and we are replacing the controls and logic with light-weight approach. So, undauntedly I don't like to implement the DataGridTemplateColumn for displaying Text Content.

Comment: @B.Balamanigandan but I suppose that using template column with textbox is the only easiest (and maybe the most efficient) way to achieve this behavior

Comment: @chameleon86 - I know that, but here easiest way is not the efficient way, it simplifies the work but in background, it definitely cause the performance issue considerably. I'm doing R&D. So, I need the efficient performance, that's I perfer the DataGridTextColumn. Kindly assist me.